# CSS alternatives to first line text-indent?

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem with how the `<p>` text-indent property is rendered when a page is printed with Internet Explorer's Active-X plugin.  Here is the relevant CSS:

```
p {
font-family: Calibri;
font-size: 20pt;
line-height: 1.75em;
margin-bottom: 1.00em;  
margin-top: 1.00em;
margin-left:1.0em;
margin-right:1.0em; 
text-indent:1.5em;  
}
```

Below you can see what is happening when the HTML page, using the above code, is printed:

[image: Improper rendering]

The top of every new page has the text indentation applied!  Is there an alternative method of having the first line of every `<p>`"paragraph tag" indented without using "text-indent" property? The solution must be browser independent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about using `::first-letter` pseudo-element?

```
p:first-letter {
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

[**JsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/q98WR/4/)

**Browser Support**

```
Chrome    Safari    Firefox    Opera    IE      Android    iOS
1+        1+        1+         3.5+     5.5+    All        All
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `pseudo elements` to mimic the effect of text-indent

```
p:before
{
    content: '\00A0 \00A0 \00A0 \00A0 \00A0 \00A0 \00A0';
    dispay:inline-block;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/q98WR/3/)**

---

**EDIT:** (As per the questioner's comments below)

If the above CSS solution(s) don't work for you, then maybe instead of using css

you could just append a fixed number of non-breaking spaces after each paragraph element.

Like so `<p>&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; ...`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/q98WR/5/)**

You could do this simply by copy/replace:

```
 <p> -> <p>&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; ...
```

Comment: Good solution, +1, just in case of browser support, I would like to tell you that IE will be the game spoiler here

Comment: Versions of IE before IE9 do not support pseudo elements, nor does Android.  Therefore Daneild's solution isn't a workable solution for me.

Comment: @user1527613 - Not true. IE8 supports them., as does all versions of android. http://caniuse.com/#search=pseudo

Comment: Here's the problem... I am not using a web browswer to display the HTML/CSS.  I am writing a software program using IWebBrowser2 interface from Microsoft’s Shell Doc Object and Control Library (SHDOCVW.DLL).  The screen snapshot you see above is the product of this DLL.  Using either of the pseudo element solutions provided above have no effect on the output. Both pseudo solutions above fail to cause the first line to indent when the HTML/CSS is rendered using this DLL.

Comment: @user1527613 If above answers still didn't work in your case, I added a new solution which probably will work